# Extension of Clairaut's theorem for partial derivatives

Tags: partial-derivative

I was wondering if anyone knows of an extension of Clairaut's theorem for interchanging the order of partial differentiation. For example, just recently I noticed that for a lot of functions

$$f_{xyy} = f_{yyx}$$.

Answer (score 1):

I would not really call that an extension. If the first order derivatives of $f$ also satisfy the conditions of Clairaut's theorem, then by two consecutive applications of that theorem

$$f_{xyy}=(f_{xy})_y=(f_{yx})_y=(f_y)_{xy}=(f_y)_{yx}=f_{yyx}$$

Comment: But is there an extension of Clairaut's theorem? That is my question.

Comment: My point was: such an extension can be formulated but the proof is so obvious that nobody bothers to give it a special name other than "repeated application of Clairaut's theorem". It's like commutativity in groups: the definition mentions exchanging the order of only 2 group elements but it is easy to conclude that any number of elements can change places.